# Why goes a ESP32-C3 into USB boot mode when solar charger isn´t used as power supply?

Tags: esp32

I have the following circuit where the ESP32-C3 goes into USB download mode then I apply 3.3 V at the marked input, but in UART download mode when I apply `VS`. I have measured the level of the `CHRG` and `FAULT` pins and both are low when 3.3 V is applied.

But the datasheet of the `LT3652` say that both pins are OC. What is the reason for measuring low levels when no `VS` is applied? I don´t get it...

[image]